# ISA SSL Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: ssl, web-server, isa-server

I'm working on solution that uploads large amount of data through web service to the server. 
Between Client and Web Service implemented ISA server. Client use certificate to authenticate on ISA server.

When I try to send data more than 200Kb I receive: `Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.`

If I send data without SSL, everything works fine. Is there are special settings on ISA server that manipulate SSL size or something like this?